# ¿Cómo hacer una clase anidada en c++?

Tags: c++, clase

Necesito hacer una clase anidada con `private`, con un ejemplo me bastaría para entender, o algún link. No he podido encontrarlo.

Comment: y cual es el objetivo de tener una clase anidada? pienso en un arreglo de la a en la clase b pero no se que intentas hacer ?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres algo más específico intenta concretar más la pregunta.

```
class Clase
{
  struct Anidada
  {
    void func(){std::cout << "Hola!!" << std::endl; }
  }

public:

  void test()
  {
    Anidada anidada;
    anidada.func();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Clase c;
  c.test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para definir una clase anidada privada en c++ puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
class MyClass
{
    // atributos de MyClass..

    private:
        class MyNestedClass
        {
              // atributos de MyNestedClass
        };
};
```

También podrías definirla y luego declararla, algo así como:

```
class MyClass
{
    // atributos de MyClass..

    private:
        class MyNestedClass;
};

class MyClass::MyNestedClass { //.. }; // definición clase anidada
```

Espero sea de utilidad. Saludos